# Is it possible to set ButtonContentProperty to a control(basically a System.Windows.Shapes.Path) using FrameworkElementFactory?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to create a custom control of type DataGrid(WPF) which accepts a list of string as columns and those columns to be altered(or customised) with a particular template[image: Image shows the requirement].

Currently I am using
 `

```
   FrameworkElementFactory buttonFact = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button));
   Path path = new Path();
   path.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
   path.StrokeThickness = 2;
   path.Data = System.Windows.Media.Geometry.Parse("M0,5 H10,10");
   buttonFact.SetValue(Button.ContentProperty, path);
```

But when I do this, I am getting exception saying

> values derived from Visual or ContentElement are not supported.

The attachment says that I should be able to expand/collapse rows based on clicking the "+" or "-".
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It doesn't seem to make sense to set the `Button.Content` property on a FrameworkElementFactory instance.

Comment: From the [Remarks on FrameworkElementFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory.aspx): *This class is a deprecated way to programmatically create templates, which are subclasses of FrameworkTemplate such as ControlTemplate or DataTemplate; not all of the template functionality is available when you create a template using this class. The recommended way to programmatically create a template is to load XAML from a string or a memory stream using the Load method of the XamlReader class.*

Comment: oh thanks Clemens for the info, I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FrameworkElementFactory, but rather than setting the Content property of the buttonFact, you must create a separate FrameworkElementFactory for the Path and use the buttonFact.AppendChild method.